# How can I pattern-match a Vec<T> inside an enum field without nesting matches?

Tags: enums, pattern-matching, rust

Pattern-matching a `Vec<T>` can be done by using either `&v[..]` or `v.as_slice()`.

```
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
match &x[..] {
    [] => println!("empty"),
    [_] => println!("one"),
    [..] => println!("many"),
}
```

If I have an enum with a field that contains the `Vec` I want to match on, I need to create a nested match inside the outer match arm:

```
enum Test {
    Many(Vec<u8>),
    Text(String),
}

fn main() {
    let x = Test::Many(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    match x {
        Test::Text(s) => println!("{}", s),
        Test::Many(v) => match &v[..] {
            [] => println!("empty"),
            [_] => println!("one"),
            [..] => println!("many"),
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do, is to match directly on the `Vec` as in the following example:

```
match x {
    Test::Text(s) => println!("{}", s),
    Test::Many([]) => println!("empty"),
    Test::Many([_]) => println!("one"),
    Test::Many([..]) => println!("many"),
}
```

I am guessing it was possible before [unique vectors got removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/12244/files#diff-ca04b724f2df29e92436ba8d2e09e18bL12)? Or am I missing some magic using `ref` that can solve this?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to do this directly, unfortunately. However, there is desire to possibly add "`Deref` patterns", which would allow pattern matching through any types which implement `Deref` or `DerefMut`, e.g. one could match on the `T` inside a `Box<T>`, or on the `[T]` "inside" a `Vec<T>`.