# How do I destructure a vector without taking a slice?

Tags: vector, rust, pattern-matching, slice, destructuring

I can destructure a vector of tuples by taking a slice of a vector and references to the items within the tuple:

```
let items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

if let [(ref name, ref age)] = items.as_slice() {
    println!("{} scored {}", name, age);
};
```

How can I destructure the vector directly, moving the items out of the tuple. Something like this:

```
let items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

if let [(name, age)] = items {
    println!("{} scored {}", name, age);
};
```

Compiling the above results in the error:

```
error[E0529]: expected an array or slice, found `std::vec::Vec<(std::string::String, {integer})>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     if let [(name, age)] = items {
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pattern cannot match with input type `std::vec::Vec<(std::string::String, {integer})>`
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851989/how-can-i-pattern-match-a-vect-inside-an-enum-field-without-nesting-matches

Comment: for future visitors: there is a proposal for deref patterns coming to rust. This will let you deref Box, Arc, Vec, and other types

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are asking two disjoint questions at once:

1. How can I move out of a vector?
2. How can I destructure an item?

The second is easy:

```
let item = ("Peter".to_string(), 180);
let (name, score) = item;
```

You don't need the `if let` syntax because there no way for this pattern-matching to fail. Of course, you can't use `item` after destructuring it because you've *transferred ownership* from `item` to `name` and `score`.

The first question is harder, and gets to a core part of Rust. If you transfer ownership out of a vector, then *what state is the vector in*? In C, you would have some undefined chunk of memory sitting in the vector, waiting to blow apart your program. Say you called `free` on that string, then what happens when you use the thing in the vector that pointed to the same string?

There are a few ways to solve it...

#### The vector continues to own the items

```
let items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

if let Some((name, score)) = items.first() {
    println!("{} scored {}", name, score);
}
```

Here, we grab *a reference to* the first item and then references to the name and score. Since the vector may not have any items, it returns an `Option`, so we do use `if let`. The compiler will not let us use these items any longer than the vector lives.

#### Transfer one element's ownership from the vector

```
let mut items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

let (name, score) = items.remove(0); // Potential panic!
println!("{} scored {}", name, score);
```

Here, we `remove` the first item from the array. The vector no longer owns it, and we can do whatever we want with it. We destructure it immediately. `items`, `name` and `score` will all have independent lifetimes.

#### Transfer all element ownership from the vector

```
let items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

for (name, score) in items {
    println!("{} scored {}", name, score);
}
```

Here, we *consume* the vector, so it is no longer available to use after the `for` loop. Ownership of `name` and `score` is transferred to the variables in the loop binding.

#### Clone the item

```
let items = vec![("Peter".to_string(), 180)];

let (name, score) = items[0].clone(); // Potential panic!
println!("{} scored {}", name, score);
```

Here, we make *new* versions of the items in the vector. We own the new items, and the vector owns the original ones.

Comment: Thanks! It's a shame that moving items out of a vector can't be supported by the compiler transferring ownership in the same way as it does when destructuring the `item` tuple.

Comment: @PeterHorne I'm not sure what you mean. If `foo = vec[0]` transferred ownership out of the vector and into the variable `foo`, what would you want `vec[0]` to mean *after* the ownership was transferred?

Comment: Same as if you try to access `items` after `(a, b) = items` – an error (use of partially moved value)

Comment: @PeterHorne: You are vastly over-estimating the Rust type system of the moment though. Partial Moves are only available for structures for which the `Drop` trait is not implemented (see http://is.gd/tRTWDR => *cannot move out of type `Person`, which defines the `Drop` trait*), because then the compiler cannot know what the `Drop` trait will rely on.

Comment: If you do need to use `.remove(0)`, changing the data structure to a `VecDeque` and using `.pop_front()` will give you better performance, and no panic.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this, [the definition of Vec in std](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L143) is

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    ptr: Unique<T>,
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
}
```

so you can't match it directly, only:

```
match xs {
    Vec { ptr: x, .. } => {...}
}
```

but

```
error: field `ptr` of struct `collections::vec::Vec` is private
```

Comment: And even if you could, you probably shouldn't and wouldn't want to mess with the pointer directly.

Comment: sure, just demonstrate how to match a Vec